# How do I pass cookies ai-user & ai_session as a dynamic variable to UserSessionid & AppSessionid in JMeter?

Tags: cookies, jmeter, session-cookies, session-variables, usersession

I want to know how to make UserSessionid & AppSessionid values dynamic. Kindy give me solution.
As I want to pass variable as a value to **UserSession** & **AppSession** in *Http sampler request header*, from which response I get those values? So I can get value and pass.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   CookieManager.save.cookies=true
   ```
2. Restart JMeter to pick up the change
3. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan
4. That's it, now you should be able to refer the cookies from the HTTP Cookie Manager as `${COOKIE_UserSession}` and `${COOKIE_AppSession}` where required

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide)